# Error IndexError: list index out of range al crear una variable

Tags: python, lista, archivo, print

Estoy intentando crear una especie de programa de red social donde el usuario puede crear un perfil, modificarlo, consultarlo y publicar un mensaje. He creado funciones para todas estas opciones, pero estoy un poco atascada.

He conseguido que en la función de publicar_mensajes el usuario añada una nueva serie en el archivo que previamente ha guardado con sus datos de usuarios. Lo he conseguido al crear una variable nueva (proxima_serie). He añadido esa variable nueva a mi función de consultar_perfil, pero al ejecutar el programa me lanza este error: **IndexError: list index out of range**

He ido probando varias cosas, incluso sin crear la nueva variable pero no consigo avanzar. Entiendo que el problema está en que esa variable no está en la función de crear perfil, pero es que ahí no me hace falta. Entonces ¿cómo puedo cambiar la lógica para actualizar el perfil de usuario, que esos cambies se guarden en el archivo y se puedan consultar?

Este es parte del código que tengo:

```
import os

def pedir_datos():
    # Función para pedir los datos del usuario y devolverlos
    # nombre = input("¿Cómo te llamas? ").capitalize()
    apellido1 = input("¿Cuál es tu primer apellido?: ").capitalize()
    serie_favorita = input("¿Cuál es tu serie favorita de todos los tiempos? ").title()
    serie = input("¿Qué serie estás viendo ahora? ").title()
    
    return apellido1, serie_favorita, serie

def guardar_datos(nombre, apellido1, serie_favorita, serie):
    # Guarda los datos del usuario en un archivo
    archivo = open(nombre + ".user", "w", encoding = "UTF-8")
    archivo.write(nombre+"\n"+apellido1+"\n"+serie_favorita+"\n"+serie+"\n")
    archivo.close()
    
def imprimir_datos(nombre, apellido1, serie_favorita, serie):
    # Función para imprimir los datos del perfil del usuario
    perfil = nombre, apellido1, serie_favorita, serie
    print()
    print("Nombre:", nombre, apellido1)
    print("Edad:", edad, "años")
    print("Tu serie favorita:", serie_favorita)
    print("La serie que estás viendo:", serie)
    return perfil    

def crear_perfil():
    # Función que llama a pedir_datos(), imprime el mensaje de perfil creado y llama a imprimir_datos()
    nombre = input("¿Cómo te llamas? ").capitalize()
    if os.path.isfile(nombre + ".user"):
        print("Ya existe un perfil con ese nombre.")
        return
        
    apellido1, serie_favorita, serie = pedir_datos()
    guardar_datos(nombre, apellido1, serie_favorita, serie)
    print("\nTu perfil ha sido creado.\n")
    imprimir_datos(nombre, apellido1, serie_favorita, serie)

def publicar_mensaje():
    # Función que actualiza e imprime la serie que estás viendo ahora
    nombre = input("¿Cómo te llamas? ").capitalize()
    if not os.path.isfile(nombre + ".user"):
        print("\nNo existe ningún perfil con ese nombre.")
        return 

    archivo = open(nombre + ".user", "a")
    proxima_serie = input("\n¿Cuál será la próxima serie a la que te vas a enganchar? ").title()
    print("¿Sabías que", proxima_serie, "es una de nuestras favoritas?")
    archivo.write(proxima_serie)
    archivo.close()
        
def consultar_perfil():
    # Consulta los datos del perfil en los archivos
    nombre = input("¿Cómo te llamas? ").capitalize()
    if os.path.isfile(nombre + ".user"):
        archivo = open(nombre + ".user", "r", encoding = "UTF-8")
        lista = archivo.readlines()
        nombre = lista[0].strip()
        apellido1 = lista[1].strip()
        serie_favorita = lista[2].strip()
        serie = lista[3].strip()
        proxima_serie = lista[4].strip()
        print("Nombre:", nombre, apellido1)
        print("Tu serie favorita:", serie_favorita)
        print("La serie que estás viendo:", serie)
        print("La serie a la que te vas a enganchar:", proxima_serie)
        return
        
    print("\nNo existe ningún perfil con ese nombre.")
```

¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

P.D.: No sé porqué hay partes que no se indentan correctamente aunque estén formatadas como código, pero mi archivo py todo está ok.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y en todo este codigo, el problema esta en....... tene en cuenta que hay muchas cosas que no hacen a tu problema, por favor mira [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes está operación para agregar datos al archivo:

```
archivo.write(nombre + "\n" + apellido1 + "\n" + serie_favorita + "\n" + serie + "\n")
```

O sea, grabas los siguientes cuatro campos:

- nombre
- apellido1
- serie_favorita
- serie

y está otra para leerlos de vuelta:

```
    lista = archivo.readlines()
    nombre = lista[0].strip()
    apellido1 = lista[1].strip()
    serie_favorita = lista[2].strip()
    serie = lista[3].strip()
    proxima_serie = lista[4].strip()
```

Estas leyendo 5 campos cuando sólo grabastes cuatro. El campo `proxima_serie` no ha sido grabado previamente.

La solución es inicializar el campo con algún valor en `guardar_datos`. Por ejemplo, puedes dejarlo en blanco, lo que parece apropiado.

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda. La verdad es que ya lo había intentado. Dentro de guardar_datos() había creado una variable: proxima_serie = "". Pero, luego,  cuando quiero consultar el perfil esta línea sigue apareciendo vacía: print("La próxima serie a la que te vas a enganchar:", proxima_serie). Por tanto, no sé qué pasa. Si abro el archivo que se crea por usuario, sí que aparece actualizado.

Comment: @marta. Tienes que grabar la variable en el archivo.